# preg replace pattern for pipe followed by any character

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that will have pipes | in it. 
for example:

`$string = 'hello | hello <htmltags> etc|Any character';`

NO what i want to do is remove last pipe followed by ANy character.
so that my result would be following after preg_replace.

```
$replaced_string = 'hello | hello <htmltags> etc';
```

can you help me, what regular expression pattern i should use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you should replace this

```
\|[^|]*$
```

with the empty string

`\|` matches a `|`

`[^|]*$` matches 0 or more characters that are not a `|` till the end of the string (because of the `$` anchor)

in php it would look like

```
preg_replace('/\|[^|]*$/', '', $string);
```

The `/` around the regex are *regex delimiters*

[What absolutely every Programmer should know about regular expressions](http://blog.xisb.de/?p=4)
<sub>Disclaimer: My own blog</sub>

Comment: should i do preg_replace('\|[^|]*$', '', $string) ?