# preg_replace a string that contains vertical line/pipe character

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have strings like this:

```
$str1="YESYES|c|no|c|";
$str2="YESYES|c|not this|c|YES|c|or this|c|";
$str3="YES";
```

I want strings like this:

```
$str1="YESYES";
$str2="YESYESYES";
$str3="YES";
```

I thought I could use preg_replace but the fact that I'm looking at a pipe seems to cause trouble, if I go like this:

```
$i=preg_replace("//|c\|[\s\S]+?/|c\|/",'',$i);
```

I get an 'unknown modifier "|"' error. I know this must have been asked before but it's very hard to search for. What is the proper regex to use?

Comment: This might help [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549919/preg-replace-pattern-for-pipe-followed-by-any-character[/link]

Comment: This part ("`//` is a complete delimited case, after which it is looking for any modifiers(?) and finds the pipe `|`

Comment: and why not use `str_replace()`?

Comment: Try using the backslash to escape the pipe when it's a literal. `\|`

Comment: Works with the right escaping, https://regex101.com/r/kE2aZ1/1. Forward slashes (`/`) are your delimiter, backslahes are for escaping and/or metacharacters.

Comment: And might need to make it greedy `'~\|c\|.*\|c|\~'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the next line:

```
$i=preg_replace("/\|c\|[\s\S]+?\|c\|/",'',$i);
```

which is almost identical to what you have, but using \  instead of  /  to scape the pipes

Comment: Ah my mistake I was doing it the way I had learned to escape in an entirely different context. Thank you! Thanks to the other people who looked at this too.